# like to compare two value from xpath of soap

Tags: web-services, xpath, soap, soapui

I like to compare Value from Soap service response via Soap Xpath assertion i.e.
response contains a result tag in which I am getting two value after executing two different request  **option_A** 
                    **option_B**
how can I write Expected result in Soap xpath assertion So that it will Pass if I am getting any one (OR CONDITION)value from two (option_A , option_B)

Comment: response after executing one request <result>option_A</result>         response after executing second request <result>option_B</result>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using OR in expected result use `or` in the XPath function to evaluate if the node text is `option_A` or `option_B` and then use [`boolean(expression)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/boolean) XPath function, and use `true` as expected result:

**XPath expression**

```
boolean(//*:result[text()='option_A' or text()='option_B'])
```

**Expected result**

```
true
```

[image]

It asserts correctly for your both responses `<result>option_A</result>` and for 
`<result>option_B</result>`.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Where can I found the refrnce material for this Plz share link

Comment: @ErrorHunter there are a lot of material about XPath on internet, you can check it for example this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath